# Can WSSF 2010 be used for code generation in VB?

Tags: vb.net, code-generation, wssf

I am new to WSSF and am wondering if it would work for solution with VB as the programming language if so how to achieve it. I have seen samples which generates C# code but my project requirement is VB .Net.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Future Development](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=V3Roadmap&referringTitle=Home) section of documentation:

> VB.NET Code Gen: This feature is also available today from the [Service Factory Contrib](http://wssfcontrib.codeplex.com/) project with plans to roll it into the next official version.

So you should check the [Service Factory Contrib](http://wssfcontrib.codeplex.com/) project to get what you want.